# TestFlight crash reports missing for latest builds

Tags: xcode

From [Apple developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-crashes_organizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer.html) I learned how to download the TestFlight crash reports. In the crash organiser it shows only up to build number 3 while I have uploaded build number 6 to the TestFlight.

Now I remember that from build number 4 we used Application loader to upload the binary. Though I am not very sure if Application loader is the only reason.

Can anyone please let me know how to download TestFlight crash reports for builds 4–6?

Comment: Are your builds 4–6 how recent? From the documentation (you linked to): "However, there may be up to a **three day delay** between when you first distribute your app and when crash reports are available in Xcode."

Comment: 4th build was uploaded Jun 20 and 5th was uploaded Jun 21 and 6th on Jun 27. So according to the upto 72 hours delay I suppose to get 4th and 5th build. But still I can only see upto build no 3.

Comment: @TapasPal did you ever figure out a solution? I'm having a similar problem viewing crash reports in TestFlight.